# Having hasOwnProperty as a key and while looping throws an error

Tags: javascript

I admit we won't have such use case/scenario in our development. However I'm just curious to know why the below code throws an error,

I have a `key` named `hasOwnProperty` and its `value` also has the same thing as this,

```
var obj = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "hasOwnProperty" : "hasOwnProperty",
    "key2": "value2"
};
```

While looping through the above object and while trying to print the key/values in the console using the below code,

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(key + "==> " + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

it throws an error stating Uncaught

```
TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

I'm just curious to know why the looping fails in this case.

Comment: becasue you've monkey patched it

Comment: `const obj = { a: function () {} }`. Then `obj.a = 123`. Question: what is `obj.a` now?

Comment: @dfsq not a function thats for sure xD

Comment: Why downvoting??? State reason please?

Comment: You could use a technique called "debugging". For example, place the command `console.log(obj.hasObjProperty); ` as the first statement in the `for` loop block,and see what it says. Or, place a breakpoint there, wait for it to stop there, and examine the value of `obj`, including its `hasOwnProperty` property. The likely reason for downvoting is that the question "does not show any research effort, or is not useful", which is the criteria. It is not useful, because it is obvious, even to a beginner, that if you set an object's property to something, then its value will now be that something.

Comment: @torazaburo I did, My question is not about making it work..

Comment: @DavidR I'm confused about your confusion. `obj.hasOwnProperty` has one and only one value. For an object without its own `hasOwnProperty`, it's the one from the `Object` prototype. For an object with its own `hasOwnProperty`, then it's that. It can't be both at the same time. If you set your own value of `hasOwnProperty` on the object, and then try to call it like a function, and it's not, then that's an error. I'm puzzled why this is hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "hasOwnProperty" : "hasOwnProperty",
    "key2": "value2"
};

// You've over written the prototype hasOwnProperty
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty)
// but the prototype is still present 
console.log(obj.__proto__.hasOwnProperty)
```

Heres some pitfalls of monkey patching

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

Because you add a property `hasOwnProperty` with a non function to the object and omit the use of the prototype `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.